# IronRuby download file using the WebClient "Not enough storage is available to process this command"

Tags: string, screen-scraping, webclient, ironruby

Entering the following two lines into an interactive window in IronRuby interactive console.

```
wc = System::Net::WebClient.new
doc = wc.DownloadString("http://yahoo.com")
```

I get the following error.

```
=> mscorlib:0:in `WinIOError': Not enough storage is available to process this command.\r\n (IOError)
    from mscorlib:0:in `Write'
    from (ir):1
```

**Edit:** looks like it's related to strings in general. The following produces the same error
    x = "String" * 40000

**Edit:**
looks like my problems are related to interactive console.
http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=23485&group_id=4359&atid=16798

if I use this

```
wc = System::Net::WebClient.new
doc = wc.DownloadString("http://yahoo.com"); nil
```

it works...

Answer (score 0):

http://ironruby.codeplex.com/workitem/5814 (bug in IR)